# How do I determine the type of an incoming post data?

Tags: vapor

I'm building an RPC based application, so incoming post data will have a general format of

```swift
struct Message: Content {
   let function: String
   let parameters: ParameterValues
}
```

Assuming I have many different message types where ParameterValues is different for all of them how do I determine what kind of message has been sent in so I can decode it?  I think I need some kind of if/else tree but if a decode fails it throws and never get's passed the first if.

```swift
if let message = request.content.decode(MessageOne) {
  // do something
} else if let message = request.content.decode(MessageTwo) {
  // do something else
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Side note I am attempting to implement a common protocol to abstract the parameters type so I don't have a ton of duplicate structs.  So we can assume all messages conform to the same protocol.

Thanks
Derek

Comment: "All you need to parse and serialize content is a `Codable` class or struct." See Vapor docs regarding [Using Content ⇗](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/vapor/content/). Consider making `struct Message` comply with the `Codable` protocol.